# latexmk: endless runs with \includestandalone[mode=buildnew]

Tags: standalone, latexmk

The following makes `latexmk` run until reaches the maximum number of runs only if `mode = buildnew` for `\includestandalone`

> Latexmk: Maximum runs of lualatex reached without getting stable files

> This message may duplicate earlier message. Latexmk:
> Failure in  processing file:
> 'lualatex' needed too many passes

`latexmk -lualatex -silent -synctex=1 -g -e "$max_repeat=3" -f -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -usepretex=\AtBeginDocument{\printanswersfalse} <file name.tex>`

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[subpreambles=false]{standalone}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{diaa_pic.tex}
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \draw[->] (0,1cm)--++(14,-5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}  
    \begin{figure}
        \includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{diaa_pic}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to John's answer, I realized that setting the option of `filecontents` to `overwrite` makes a newer `diaa_pic.tex` (with the same contents) every single run.

By passing `mode=buildnew` to `\includestandalone`, `latexmk` will be forced to create the image `diaa_pic.pdf` every run since its `tex` source is more recent than it.

So, removing the `overwite` option is more than enough to make everything work as expected.

Comment: Actually, the use of `overwrite` doesn't itself affect `latexmk`'s working.  `Latexmk` makes a new run only when the contents of a source file have changed.  A mere change of the file's time stamp doesn't count.  It's actually `tikz` that recompiles `diaa_pic.tex`, because of its more recent time stamp.

Comment: @JohnCollins You're right, and that's what is actually intended to make tikz build a new image whenever the image source has a newer timestamp than the image itself. So, it all started when I didn't pay enough attention to what I wrote :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused because compilation of the main document causes a file `diaa_pic.pdf` to be created, and that file is read in during the next compilation.  The file has a creation date etc coded in it, so it changes after every run of `pdflatex`, even without a change in the visual form.  `Latexmk` sees that the file has changed after a compilation, so it decides that another run is needed.

(By the way the document needs `\usepackage{tikz}` lines before it will compile.)

Two solutions:

1. **Simple**: Arrange for `latexmk` to ignore the relevant lines in the `pdf` file.  To do this put the following lines in a latexmkrc file:

   ```
    $hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^/(CreationDate|ModDate|ID)';
    # Also apply the same idea to eps files, so that this code works with latex
    $hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'eps'} =  '^(%%CreationDate: |%DVIPSSource: )';
    # In compilation, -shell-escape has to be used:
    set_tex_cmds( '-shell-escape %O %S' );
   ```
2. **Fancy**: look in the latexmk distribution in the `example_rcfiles` directory for the file `tikz-externalized-latexmkrc`, and use what you need from it. (That file and directory can be found under `doc/support/latexmk` in the relevant part of your TeXLive or MiKTeX distribution.)  *But note that this solution will need enhancement to deal with the particular document in this question.*

Comment: Your answer made me realize that I did something goofy by setting the option of `filecontents` to `overwrite` so that every run a new `diaa_pic.tex` is generated which makes `latexmk` go for a full cycle since the option of `\includestandalone` is set to `buildnew`.